# How to convert static property to the const property in the C#?

Tags: c#, enums, static, constants

The code below with the `static` keyword works fine but I want to make the below property as `constant` in C#.

The reason for doing so is the consistency through out the project. All the property which value is never going to change is marked as `const` not the `static or static readonly` in the existing project.

```
public class StatusList
{
public static Dictionary<DownloadStatus, int> DownlodStatusList
{
  get
  {
    return new Dictionary<DownloadStatus, int>()
        {
          { DownloadStatus.Preview, (int)DownloadStatus.Preview },
          { DownloadStatus.Active, (int)DownloadStatus.Active },
          { DownloadStatus.Expired, (int)DownloadStatus.Expired },
          { DownloadStatus.Inactive, (int)DownloadStatus.Inactive }
        };
  }
}
}
```

Comment: `const` value must be literal

Comment: You can mark property as `static` which will be same in nature as `const`

Comment: you can´t use `new ...` with `const`. That´s it.

Comment: Sorry @haim770 I have edited my code.

Comment: you can't but you could use readonly to achieve that (kind of)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

There's a difference between `static readonly` and `const`, in that whenever code references a `const`, the value of the `const` is baked directly into the point where it's referenced. Therefore a `const` can only be number, boolean, string, or null.

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/const):

> Constants can be **numbers, Boolean values, strings, or a null
>   reference.**
>
> ...
>
> The initializer of a constant local or a constant field must be a
>   constant expression that can be implicitly converted to the target
>   type. A constant expression is an expression that **can be fully
>   evaluated at compile time**. Therefore, the only possible values for
>   constants of reference types are string and a null reference.

Having said this you can´t use `const` for anything that is not a compile-time literal. This in particular includes everything that was initialized with `new`.